# While iterating through a loop some items are getting missed out

Tags: ewam

The method that I am trying to run is as below where I try iterate through the sub contracts in a GBP and then I have an inner loop to iterate through the coverages in each sub contract.

```
forEach curSubscribedSubContract in theSubContracts
   ; Avoid building empty contract node
   if subOptions.count > 0
      new(ParamProduct)
      new(ParamSubscribedProduct)
      forEach curOption in subOptions downTo 
         theProduct = curOption.GetProduct
         new(ListOfCoverages)
         if Motor.AreSameThings(theProduct, curSubscribedSubContract.GetProduct)
            ParamSubscribedProduct.InitParamFromObjectAtDate(curSubscribedSubContract, 
               AtDate)
            ParamProduct.Product = ParamSubscribedProduct
            ;Set Context for PlanDesign options
            AFCI_SLI.CoverageInContext = curOption
            covData = self._GetCoverageData(curOption, AtDate)
            ;Reset coverage context               
            AFCI_SLI.CoverageInContext = Nil
            ListOfCoverages.AppendObject(covData)
            if subOptions.RemoveObject(curOption)
            endIf
         endIf
         forEach curCoverageData in ListOfCoverages
            ParamProduct.Coverages[-1] = curCoverageData
         endFor
         dispose(ListOfCoverages)
      endFor
      _Result[-1] = ParamProduct
   endIf
endFor
```

Answer (score 1):

are items missing from the subcontracts or suboptions?

I think the following line of code has something to do with it:

```
if subOptions.RemoveObject(curOption)
endIf
```

I am not sure if it is a good practice to remove objects from a list which is being iterated..

also

try removing the 'down to" from the foreach loop of suboptions